# Security Printing in pdflatex documents

Tags: printing, draftwatermark

this is may situation. I generate a test which is printed for 1300 copies to be distributed amongst my students. However I would like to put some feature in the printed pages, such that if someone makes a PHOTOCOPY, it will be self evident to the human eye to notice the difference between the original and the photocopy. I guess my inquiry/requirement goes on the concept of [Security Printing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_printing). Here is a minimal work example, any suggestions?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}




% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% WATERMARK
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\SetWatermarkText{A}
%\SetWatermarkColor[RGB]{210,217,242}
\SetWatermarkScale{35}
\SetWatermarkAngle{0}
\SetWatermarkLightness{0.9}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %






\begin{document}

\centerline{ \textbf{ Linear Algebra Midterm} }
\centerline{\textbf{April, 18th, 2015} }


 %
%
%
%
\begin{table*}[h!]
%\caption{Notas. Solo Para Uso Oficial}
\centerline{\textbf{Score}}\vspace{5pt}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
1 & 2 & 2 & 4 &  \textbf{TOTAL}& \textbf{GRADE} \\
    \hline
\hspace{0.3in} &  
\hspace{0.3in} & \hspace{0.3in} & 
\hspace{0.3in} & \hspace{1.0in} & \hspace{1.0in}  \\[0.4cm]
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

%
\end{table*}
%
%
%
\vspace{-20pt}
%
\noindent \textbf{Instructions:} Mark the options of your choice or fill in the blanks. The test 4 questions to be answered in 60 minutes.  
\newline
\newline
\textbf{IDENTIFICATION}
\newline
\newline
Name: \hrulefill \hrulefill \hrulefill ID Number \hrulefill

\bigskip

Professor: \hrulefill \hrulefill \hrulefill Group \hrulefill

\bigskip




\begin{itemize}

\item $[8 pt]$ Find the real scalars $k$ such that $||kv||=3$ where $v=[-1,2,7,-3]$, 
$k=$\rule{3cm}{0.4pt}

\vspace{2cm}
\item $[8 pt]$ Determine whether the systems have trivial solutions or not.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
x_1+3x_2+5x_3+x_4=0   \\
4x_1-7x_2-3x_3-x_4=0  \\
3x_1+2x_2+7x_3+8x_4=0\\
\hrulefill 
\end{gathered} \hspace{3cm}
\begin{gathered}
x+2y+3z=0\\
y+4z=0\\
5z=0\\
\hrulefill 
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}


\item $[6 pt]$ Let $A,B$ be $4 \times 5$ matrices and $C,D$ and $E$ matrices of size $5 \times 2$, $4 \times 2$ and $5 \times 4$ respectively. Determine if the following matrix operations are well-defined.
\begin {itemize}
\item $BA$ \rule{3cm}{0.4pt}
\item $AC+D$ \rule{3cm}{0.4pt}
\item $AE+B$ \rule{3cm}{0.4pt}
\end{itemize}


\vspace{2cm}
\item $[6 pt]$ Suppose that a $3 \times 3$ matrix has all its entries equal to a non-null constant. What is the range of the matrix? \hrulefill.

%
\end{itemize}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that grayscale alone will suffice with modern technology.  I seem to recall (maybe I'm imagining it) that security measures employ gratings, which are much harder to faithfully reproduce.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You mean like making carrot cake?

Comment: Are the 1300 copies identical or are they numbered or otherwise identifiable?

Comment: Well I already added a distinctive number for each test with a loop from 1 to 1300 (I did not put it to keep the example minimal). But I am afraid that will not suffice to stop the photocopier.

Comment: One thing I've heard to uniquely identify each test is to introduce a unique one-letter typo into each printed copy.  That way, when a duplicate shows up, it can be identified.  Most importantly, it doesn't tip off the offender, unless he knows what he is looking for.  You need a macro that takes a "question" string and introduces typos based on the page index.

Comment: The `automultiplechoice` package can make easily unique numbered exams for each student (randomly mixed or even different questions). When test are scanned with the answers, the AMC program identify both the number of the test and the identity number of the student, so it someone make the exam of another student the program will show you that. If you assign each test by alphabetic order, is easy determine which of them present the original and who present a photocopy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I submit to you that this will not copy well.  Elements used include:

1. two colors (plus black)
2. contrast of dark and light printing
3. diffraction-grate-like patterns

Here is the MWE.  You can play with the colors and their intensity.  I had five such figures to see the effect of the shift on the copy outcome.  The whole design is contained in the preamble.  I use `everypage` to place it on every page.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz,everypage}
% THESE ARE LaTeX DEFAULTS; CAN CHANGE IF NEEDED.
\def\PageTopMargin{1in}
\def\PageLeftMargin{1in}
\newcommand\atxy[3]{%
 \AddEverypageHook{\smash{\hspace*{\dimexpr-\PageLeftMargin-\hoffset+#1\relax}%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr\PageTopMargin+\voffset-#2\relax}{\textcolor{red}{#3}}}}}
% VERIFIED THAT SETTING \hoffset AND \voffset DO NOT BREAK SOLUTION.
%\hoffset=0.4in
%\voffset=0.2in
\newsavebox\bgrate
\savebox\bgrate{\color{red!20}%
\tikz{%
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=3.25em]{\Huge\textcolor{black}{X}};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=3.00em]{};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=2.75em]{};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=2.50em]{};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=2.25em]{};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=2.00em]{};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=1.75em]{};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=1.50em]{};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=1.25em]{};
\node[circle,draw]{};
}}
\newsavebox\rgrate
\savebox\rgrate{\color{red!20!green!15}%
\tikz{%
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=3.25em]{\Huge\textcolor{black}{X}};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=3.00em]{};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=2.75em]{};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=2.50em]{};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=2.25em]{};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=2.00em]{};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=1.75em]{};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=1.50em]{};
\node[circle,draw,minimum height=1.25em]{};
\node[circle,draw]{};
}}
\def\thegrate{%
\ooalign{\usebox{\bgrate}\cr\kern.7pt\usebox{\rgrate}}%
\ooalign{\usebox{\bgrate}\cr\kern1pt\usebox{\rgrate}}%
\ooalign{\usebox{\bgrate}\cr\kern1.2pt\usebox{\rgrate}}%
\ooalign{\usebox{\bgrate}\cr\kern1.7pt\usebox{\rgrate}}%
\ooalign{\usebox{\bgrate}\cr\kern2.3pt\usebox{\rgrate}}%
}

\atxy{0.1in}{.57in}{\thegrate}

\begin{document}

\centerline{ \textbf{ Linear Algebra Midterm} }
\centerline{\textbf{April, 18th, 2015} }


 %
%
%
%
\begin{table*}[h!]
%\caption{Notas. Solo Para Uso Oficial}
\centerline{\textbf{Score}}\vspace{5pt}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
1 & 2 & 2 & 4 &  \textbf{TOTAL}& \textbf{GRADE} \\
    \hline
\hspace{0.3in} &  
\hspace{0.3in} & \hspace{0.3in} & 
\hspace{0.3in} & \hspace{1.0in} & \hspace{1.0in}  \\[0.4cm]
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

%
\end{table*}
%
%
%
\vspace{-20pt}
%
\noindent \textbf{Instructions:} Mark the options of your choice or fill in the blanks. The test 4 questions to be answered in 60 minutes.  
\newline
\newline
\textbf{IDENTIFICATION}
\newline
\newline
Name: \hrulefill \hrulefill \hrulefill ID Number \hrulefill

\bigskip

Professor: \hrulefill \hrulefill \hrulefill Group \hrulefill

\bigskip




\begin{itemize}

\item $[8 pt]$ Find the real scalars $k$ such that $||kv||=3$ where $v=[-1,2,7,-3]$, 
$k=$\rule{3cm}{0.4pt}

\vspace{2cm}
\item $[8 pt]$ Determine whether the systems have trivial solutions or not.

\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
x_1+3x_2+5x_3+x_4=0   \\
4x_1-7x_2-3x_3-x_4=0  \\
3x_1+2x_2+7x_3+8x_4=0\\
\hrulefill 
\end{gathered} \hspace{3cm}
\begin{gathered}
x+2y+3z=0\\
y+4z=0\\
5z=0\\
\hrulefill 
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}


\item $[6 pt]$ Let $A,B$ be $4 \times 5$ matrices and $C,D$ and $E$ matrices of size $5 \times 2$, $4 \times 2$ and $5 \times 4$ respectively. Determine if the following matrix operations are well-defined.
\begin {itemize}
\item $BA$ \rule{3cm}{0.4pt}
\item $AC+D$ \rule{3cm}{0.4pt}
\item $AE+B$ \rule{3cm}{0.4pt}
\end{itemize}


\vspace{2cm}
\item $[6 pt]$ Suppose that a $3 \times 3$ matrix has all its entries equal to a non-null constant. What is the range of the matrix? \hrulefill.

%
\end{itemize}
%


\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a zoom of the... the... the blivets:

[image]

Here is a scan of the original paper (above) and the color photocopy (below).  The contrast (hah hah) is obvious.

[image]

Comment: Hey!!!! Your solution is fantastic!!!! It works even in gray scales (my printer is black an white)!!! Thanks a lot, it was just what I needed.

Comment: @Fernando Awesome.  If this answer is one that answers your question in the best way, then the protocol is to click the check mark to the left of my answer to "accept" it.  For any answers that may arise to your question (whether they are accepted or not), clicking the up arrow to the left of the question indicates that the answer had some merit or showed some effort.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Done!!! Thanks for telling me about the protocol. I am new in the neighborhood...